# how display current user in debug mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

please help display current_user.

i use rails4 + devise + rspec + capybara. i try signin user.

test:

```
it 'check display username on top panel' do
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_in user
  visit root_path
  binding.pry      
end
```

factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name){ |i| "us#{i}" }
    sequence(:email){ |i| "us#{i}@ad.ad" }
    password 'qwerty'
    password_confirmation{ |u| u.password } 
  end
end
```

rails_helper:

```
..........
..............
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...........
  ..........

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

but I can not display the current user.

console output:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController>)> puts user.id
1
=> nil
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController>)> puts user
#<User:0x000000086cee10>
=> nil
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController>)> puts current_user
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController:0x0000000863d348>
from /home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-expectations-3.3.0/lib/rspec/matchers.rb:966:in `method_missing'
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController>)>
```

Comment: Why do you need name `current_user`? You have a `user` right there.

Comment: I need to check whether or not a user entered

Comment: if you do `binding.pry` in controller itself

Answer (score 1):

If you needs to check login user or not - try to call `user_signed_in?` helper after `sign_in user`

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subject.current_user` to access the current logged in user.